# how can i use fillna(inplace=True) in for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, fillna, in-place

```
df = pd.read_csv('IMDB-Movie-Data.csv')

dp = df.groupby('Director')['Revenue (Millions)'].mean()
for i in dp.index:
    df.loc[df['Director']==i,'Revenue (Millions)'].fillna(dp[i],inplace = True)
```

sorry for bad English
dp is Revenue column's mean values grouped by Director column.
dp.index means Directors
i dont know why that code is not working. 
i want nan values in Revenue columns to be changed to mean values that is grouped by Directors 
Help me....
there is no errors but not working....squid games...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
df = pd.read_csv('IMDB-Movie-Data.csv')

dp = df.groupby('Director')['Revenue (Millions)'].mean()
df['Revenue (Millions)'].fillna(df.groupby('Director')['Revenue (Millions)'].transform('mean'),inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want to change nan values to mean values for each Director

Comment: i've edited my answer, maybe give that a try

Comment: @이희건 edited again !! sorry, i don't think you'll need a loop